# Working with WPF & SQL database

Tags: sql, wpf, database

I'm into creating a simple contact management application to test how WPF works with SQL database. is there any WPF-code for that shows how to connect with SQL database ? save and update data?

I'm using **KaXML/Sharp-develop** for WPF and using **SQLite/MS-SQL server 200**5.

I can't use Visual studio express(not allowed to install,anyway that's another issue)

Do i need to work with cs files (c# code) for this ?

(Sorry, very limited links regarding this using google)

any help with how to add data grid and relative code will help a lot.
other than that you can point me to question/blog posts/forum entry that covers my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few [good starter videos in WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx)

For this task I recommend you [How Do I: Create a Simple WPF DataGrid to Edit Tabular Data](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=83530)